# SystemChannels.lifecycle.setMessageHandler freezes my app in release mode

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I am using SystemChannels.lifecycle to monitor when my app is resumed.

My code was working fine when I am in debug mode. But when I switched to release mode the app would just load to a white screen and hang.

The offending code is as follows...

```
SystemChannels.lifecycle.setMessageHandler((String msg) async {
    return "";
});
```

If I uncomment this code, my app runs fine in release. If I add it back in, the app will not work, and only loads to a white screen, and the UI does not load.

For more context, here is the code in my main.dart...

```
void main() {

    TimeServer.instance.update();

    final GlobalKey<NavigatorState> navigatorKey = new GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();

    runZonedGuarded(() {
        runApp(MyApp(navigatorKey));
        },
        Log.onError
    );

    SystemChannels.lifecycle.setMessageHandler((String msg) async {
        return "";
    });
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {

    final GlobalKey<NavigatorState> navigatorKey;

    MyApp(this.navigatorKey);

    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return OverlaySupport(
          child:  MaterialApp(
                title: 'Flutter Demo',
                theme: ThemeData(
                    primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
                ),
                navigatorKey: navigatorKey,
                onGenerateRoute: NavBoss.generateRoutes
            ),
        );
    }
}
```

When I run the app in debug it works fine everywhere. When I run the app in release on my Moto g5, it fails 100% of the time. When I run the app on my Nexus 6p android 28 emulator, it fails randomly about 25% of the time.

Comment: I have the same exact problem